# access the Window's DataContext from within a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have some problem to access the Window's DataContext from within a DataGrid.

The DataGrid is bound to a IBindingList:

```
public IBindingList Items{ get; set; }
    private void initItems()
    {
        //ItemFactory is a Linq2SQL Context, Items is the view of availabe Items
        this.Items = this.ItemFactory.Items.GetNewBindingList();
    }
```

From within my xaml I try to get those data to fill a ComboBox:

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Typ" 
                             DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                             SelectedValuePath="ItemID"      
                             ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Mode=OneWay, Path=DataContext.Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

But it doesn't work. I tried out many variants already. The ComboBox gets not populated.
Any help greatly appreciated!

**Note:**

The following ComboBox in the same Window does work:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="workingCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="ItemID" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is not directly connected to the visual tree and therefore the `FindAncestor`-operation will fail (and also the DataContext will not be inherited).

- The most simple solution is to
  **create a ViewModel** for each line and provide there in the ItemsSource
  for the ComboBox.
- **Using a `DataGridTemplateColumn`** and placing the `ComboBox` in the
  `DataTemplate` helps.
- [Here](http://joemorrison.org/blog/2009/02/17/excedrin-headache-35401281-using-combo-boxes-with-the-wpf-datagrid)
  is a another post concerning this problem. And look also at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrid-s-datacontext-to-its-columns.aspx)
  post.

Comment: Thank you for this good answer! I didn't find those 2 posts by googling.  
- The problem about using a ViewModel for each row is that I bind the BindingList directly to the DataGrid's ItemSource.
- If I have to use a DataGridTemplateColumn.. what's a DataGridComboBoxColumn worth?..guess one can only use it with static defined collections then.
I'll try this out at work tomorrow and then mark it as answer when I succeed ;) ty again

Comment: It worked using the RelativePath when I use a ComboBox in a DataGridTemplateColumn

Comment: I know the answer is almost 10 years old, but the second link is not working anymore.